# Flutter Scrollable layout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am making a flutter layout with several items in it. It is a column with several widgets among them a gridview containing several items. I would like to make the whole layout scrollable however even after wrapping the main widget in a singlechildscrollview it is not scrollable
This is the code

```
class _CustomerDataState extends State<CustomerData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Customer Data'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: _containers());
  }

  Widget _containers() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(elevation: 5.0, child: Text('Information')),
          Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[Text('No: '), Text('....')],
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[Text('Stages: '), Text('....')],
            ),
          ),
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                  elevation: 5.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
                      Text('First Stage')
                    ],
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                elevation: 8.0,
                child: Text('Words here'),
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 8.0,
                child: Text('Words here'),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And is there a way I can center the icon and text in the card widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `ScrollController` is the one responsible for scrolling behavior, yet your gridview is not using one, consider creating a ScrollController and assign it to the gridview

```
ScrollController _scrollControllerGridView` = ScrollController()

 GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            controller: _scrollControllerGridView,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
...
```

and to center the card's text and icon
just add

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

to the Column, like this:

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
     Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
     Text('First Stage')
  ],
)
```